# Hatch Pattern with 3D Path (path3) / Surface in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I can obtain hatch for simple 2D paths:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";

unitsize(1cm);
import patterns;

path aaa = (0,0)..(3,-1)..(6,0)--cycle;
add("hatch", hatch());
filldraw(aaa, pattern("hatch"));

shipout(currentpicture.fit());
```

[image]

If I want to do the same thing in 3D, with path3, it does not work:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.render=16;
settings.prc = false;

unitsize(1cm);
import graph3;
import three;
import patterns;

add("hatch", hatch());

path3 bbb = (0,0,0)..(3,-1,0)..(6,0,0)--cycle;
draw(bbb, pattern("hatch"));

shipout(currentpicture.fit());
```

[image]

How can I add hatch pattern to a 3D surface?

Comment: What about `filldraw(project(bbb), pattern("hatch"));`  ?

Comment: @g.kov oh, it works well!

Comment: @g.kov worked like a charm. Could you please post it as an answer? So the idea here is, first convert the 3D path3 to a 2D path with `project` and apply `filldraw`

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. And about an answer - well,
would you mind to make it as a self-answer instead?